# How to use JQuery functions with Knockout Extenders

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

How do I use jQuery functions in a custom knockout extender. Here is an example of adding a class to a knockout target from a custom extender.

```
ko.extenders.addClass = function(target, option) {
    if (option == true)
    {
        target.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            $(this.target).addClass('new_class');
        });
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: If you specifically want to add a class, you can use the built-in `css` binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine a normal [dirty-flag](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html) with the css-binding.

```
ko.dirtyFlag = function(root) {
    var result = function() {}, // A function will not get serialized to JSON
        _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root));

    result.isDirty = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        return _initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
    });

    result.reset = function() {
        _initialState(ko.toJSON(root));
    };

    return result;
};

function ViewModel() {
    // Normal properties
    this.someProperty = ko.observable("initial value");

    // Dirty-flag for this object.
    this.dirtyFlag = ko.dirtyFlag(this);
}
```

```html
<div data-bind="css: { 'new_class': dirtyFlag.isDirty }"></div>
```

You could also pass an observable, or an array of observables, if you want to track just a subset of the properties.

```
this.dirtyFlag = ko.dirtyFlag(this.someProperty);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MizardX/7esdy/

Comment: Why are you subscribing to the observable? The update method is already doing this for you. The update method will trigger each time you change the observable, this way you will get multiple subscriptions to the observable (One for each time the value change). Please fix or i will downvote